# Counter cache with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have added a feature to my app where I can count the unique visitors on two specific pages. This is the setup I have:

```
class Impression < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :impressionable, :polymorphic => true, counter_cache: :impressions_count
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :impressions, :as=>:impressionable

  def impression_count
    impressions.size
  end

  def unique_impression_count
    impressions.group(:ip_address).size.keys.length
  end
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :impressions, :as=>:impressionable

  def impression_count
    impressions.size
  end

  def unique_impression_count
    impressions.group(:ip_address).size.keys.length
  end
end

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :log_impression, :only=> [:show]


  def log_impression
    @product.impressions.find_or_create_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
  end
end


class VariantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :log_impression, :only=> [:show]


  def log_impression
    @variant.impressions.find_or_create_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
  end
end
```

Everything works just fine. Each time I visit the specific show pages an impression is created inside the db.

Now I'm trying to implement a most viewed products/variants loop. First I combined the two arrays(products & variants) and then I'm sorting them by `impressions_count`. I aded a `t.integer :impressions_count` column to both the product and variant models. And also I'm updating the column each time with a `counter_cache: :impressions_count` inside the `Impression Model`, as you can see in the above setup.

```
inventory = current_user.store.products.order('impressions_count DESC').limit(5) | current_user.store.variants.order('impressions_count DESC').limit(5)
@top_products =  inventory.sort_by { |st| st['impressions_count'].to_i }.reverse
```

Everything works just fine but the only thing I have noticed is that when I do this inside a view:

```
 <% @top_products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.unique_impression_count %> 
 <% end %>
```

The above loop shows 1 view! Which I believe is correct because I'm counting the unique views from each IP.

On the other hand the `impressions_count` column shows a different number and messes up the  `@top_products =  inventory.sort_by { |st| st['impressions_count'].to_i }.reverse` method.

And also the `impressions_count` column gets updated each time I visit the show pages.

Is there a way I can add a unique condition to the `counter_cache: :impressions_count` in order to update the column only if a visitor is from another IP?

Comment: I'm not sure what the root cause of your problem is; I'd need to look at the data and try debugging a bit ... But I'm a bit confused why your implementation seems over-complicated; you're only trying to log one impression per IP address (`find_or_create_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)`), so why is there all this additional code trying to group by IP address (`impressions.group(:ip_address).size`)?

Comment: In other words, I don't understand why you have separate implementations for e.g. `Product#impression_count` and `Product#unique_impression_count` -- aren't they supposed to be exactly the same thing? You could also at least add a uniqueness validation to the impressions: `validates :impressionable_id, uniqueness: { scope: [: ip_address] }`, or even make it a database constraint.

Comment: In terms of debugging, one thing I'd do is ensure your data makes sense - i.e. that you do indeed only have 1 impression per IP address per product/variant. If there's more than 1, then there's possibly a bug in your code, and definitely an issue with your data.

Comment: A "counter cache" merely caches the number of associated records, so you can avoid the `COUNT(*)` query. It is handles by Rails automatically, you're not supposed to alter the column yourself or to override the `impression_count` method (as you did). If you want to track both, page impressions and unique visits, it might be best to add a separate `UniqueVisit` model with its own `unique_visits_count` counter cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tom Lord! You're right, there was no point in having both `Product#impression_count` & `Product#unique_impression_count`. So I deleted the `Product#unique_impression_count` and added this to both the variant and product models `validates :impressionable_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:ip_address] }`. Now it only seems to update the `impression_count` column when it creates a new impression record. Even though I'm still in development and I can't test this with another IP, do you think that this approach is correct and will it work when in production?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stefan. So basically you're suggesting to create a new model and go from there. But what should be the `UniqueVisits` model associations and how will I be able to count the `unique_visits_count` from the array(product/variants) I'm combining. Can you please be more specific with your answer. I'm kind of new with rails!

Comment: @Dev *"I can't test this with another IP"* -- You should really be testing this by *writing tests*, not by relying on the developer to manually check that it's behaving as you expect. And in the tests, you can stub the IP address in order to simulate different users. However, if you really want to verify it in your local environment, you could add some temporary "hack" to persist records with other dummy IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Tom Lord!! I appreciate the help! :))))))